# Node.js - res.redirect not working

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Iam a beginner to node.js and iam currently working on an express.js redirect routine. 
The code works so far, the session variable is being stored and the redirects are working fine.
But as soon I open a new tab and try to enter an url like (127.0.0.1/login.ejs) it should redirect to hub.ejs if iam logged in. But in this case the redirect does not work. It is the same problem if I am not logged in and enter for example (127.0.0.1/hub.ejs) in a new tab. The redirect should load login.ejs but nothing is working at all. The page stays empty

```
app.get("/login.ejs", function(req, res)
{
    if(!req.session.userName)
    {
        res.render(__dirname + "/login.ejs");
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect(__dirname + "/hub.ejs");
    }
});

app.get("/hub.ejs", function(req, res)
{
if(req.session.userName)
{
        res.render(__dirname + "/hub.ejs", {userName: req.session.userName,     clients: clients});
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect(__dirname + "/login.ejs");
    }
});
```

Comment: redirect documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.userName && req.baseUrl !== 'login.ejs') {
        return res.render(__dirname + "/login.ejs");
    }
    next();
})

app.get("/login.ejs", function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.userName) {
        return res.redirect(__dirname + "/hub.ejs");
    }
    res.render(__dirname + "/login.ejs");
});

app.get("/hub.ejs", function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + "/hub.ejs", {userName: req.session.userName,     clients: clients});
});
```

The first function block, `app.use` is express middleware which will be executed for all routes defined *after* it. What it does is check if the session is unavailable and the user is not requesting the login page (to prevent redirection loops). The user will be redirected to the login page if he is not logged in and otherwise the correct route will be executed.

For the `login.ejs` We simply check if a session is set and redirect to the hub. Notice the `return` statement to prevent the rendering of the `login.ejs` page.

For the `hub.ejs` we simply render that page. If the user is not logged in he will simply be redirected to the login page because of our middleware. The `app.get("/hub.ejs"` will then simply not be executed.

Note that the code should appear in this particular order for it to work (Middlware first, routes second).